# Looping Logic in Java

Tags: java, loops

I have not programmed in a while and I am trying to get back into the swing of things and this is how far I have gotten. My question, is how do I loop the second question so that if the response is something besides a yes or no it asks the question again. I have tried putting a loop around the if statement, but whenever I try and get another response from the user it tells me I cannot use the variable, *response*, to do so. I feel this is an easy fix for I understand looping, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this specific issue, thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to my simulation, please enter your name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + " would you like to play a game?");
        String response = input.nextLine();


        boolean yes = new String("yes").equals(response.toLowerCase());
        boolean no = new String("no").equals(response.toLowerCase());


        if (yes){
            System.out.println("Which game woudl you like to play?");
        }else if (no){
            System.out.println("Fine then, have a good day!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("please enter either yes or no");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `new String("yes")`. `"yes"` will do fine.

Comment: The "swing" of things..heh..

Comment: @Eric but... there's no Swing in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here's the first that came to mind:

```
while (true) {
    response = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    if (response.equals("yes") {
        System.out.println("Which game woudl you like to play?");
        break;
    } else if (response.equals("no") {
        System.out.println("Fine then, have a good day!");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("please enter either yes or no");
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had to bring my boolean statements within the loop but after that it worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First off, to make it easier on yourself, you don't need to use `boolean` variables. You can simply use the `.equals()` method to test if the response is equal to yes or no. In this case, it would be easier to use if else statements like this:

```
if (response.equals("Yes"))
{
    System.out.println("Which game woudl you like to play?");
}

else if (response.equals("No"))
{    
    System.out.println("Fine then, have a good day!");
}

else if (!response.equals("Yes") && !response.equals("No"))
{
    while (!response.equals("Yes") && !response.equals("No"))
    {
        System.out.println("please enter either yes or no");
        response = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: I know, I was just practicing the use of my booleans because before I found out about using them in this way I had no idea you could do so.

Comment: I understand. There are so many ways it can be done. There's a world of this stuff out there. Its really good to practice as I have found out in the last year or so

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
do{
    String response = input.nextLine();
    boolean yes = new String("yes").equals(response.toLowerCase());
    boolean no = new String("no").equals(response.toLowerCase());
    if (yes){
        System.out.println("Which game woudl you like to play?");
    }else if (no){
        System.out.println("Fine then, have a good day!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("please enter either yes or no");
    }
}while(!response.equals("yes") && !response.equals("no"));
```

Comment: i didn't downvote. But your code would loop either once or infinitly because response never changes in it.